# How do I geom_text a secondary data.frame into my main data.frame plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I recently made a stacked bar plot of the next data.frame:

```
dput(head(mdfrsubsetN))
structure(list(MESES = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Enero", "Febrero", 
"Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", 
"Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("19N", "19DURAC", "50N", "50DURAC", 
"PUSHN", "PUSHDURAC", "GRATISN", "GRATISDURAC"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(NA, NA, 1431, 982, 766, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

With this code:

```
  ggplot(mdfrsubsetN, aes(MESES, value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

It gives me this graph. [image: Plot without geom_text]

Now I would like to use a secondary data.frame to apply a geom_text over their corresponding bars. The data.frame has the next structure.

```
dput(head(mdfrsubsetDURAC))
structure(list(MESES = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Enero", "Febrero", 
"Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", 
"Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("19N", "19DURAC", "50N", "50DURAC", 
"PUSHN", "PUSHDURAC", "GRATISN", "GRATISDURAC"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(NA, NA, 5.04, 5.01, 4.61, NA)), row.names = 13:18, class = "data.frame")
```

I tried with the next code but the results are not what I desire.

```
  ggplot(mdfrsubsetN, aes(MESES, value, fill = variable)) +
    geom_col(position = "fill") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
    geom_text(data=mdfrsubsetDURAC, aes(x = MESES, y = value, label = value), position = "fill", vjust="center")+
    theme_classic() +
    scale_fill_discrete(name="PROMOS",
                        breaks=c("19N", "50N","PUSHN","GRATISN"),
                        labels=c("19", "50%", "PUSH", "GRATIS"))
```

Here is the result.

[image: Plot with geom_Text]

I would like the annotations to be over the right bar, since right now they are slightly above where I need them. If I could have them right on the center of each bar, it would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 geom_text(data=mdfrsubsetDURAC, aes(x = MESES, y = value, label = value), hjust = 0.5,  vjust = 0.5,position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But no, it still is out of focus. Here is the result.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1G2XTGkA_-qOvx8-NNCZ8aQE9R2ybXFzY

Comment: Could you please share a full fake reproducible data set. To test the solution as `head` only give `PROMOMS 19`

Comment: Sure. Here you have the two dataframes. The main difference will be the `x`column. 1=january and so on. 

`dataN <- data.frame(
  x = sample(c(1:12), 40, replace = TRUE),
  y = sample(c("19","50","PUSH","GRATIS"), 40, replace = TRUE),
  z = sample(1:40)
)`
AND

`dataDURAC <- data.frame(
  x = sample(c(1:12), 40, replace = TRUE),
  y = sample(c("19DURAC","50DURAC","PUSHDURAC","GRATISDURAC"), 40, replace = TRUE),
  z = sample(1:40)
)`

Comment: Provided data set does not match the posted graph. Anyhow, `hjust` and `vjust` can accept positions separately as follows: `geom_text(data=dataN, aes(x = as.factor(x), y = z, label = z), hjust = rep(0.5,nrow(dataN)),  vjust = c(.5, .25, rep(0,nrow(dataN)-2)) ,position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5))`. So, you can pass the position for each category separately